# Create input field in Google Docs form allowing only numbers

Tags: google-drive

We need to create a form asking the clients for their age. Is there any way to create a field where you can only fill in numbers - maybe only 4 numbers like 1976 or 2011?

Another field input would be date. It would be perfect if I could limit the number - something like "not lower than 1800 and not higher than 2012" to prevent invalid numbers.

I can create a question with drop down list, but creating a list of all possible years would be stupid and uncomfortable to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Google Spreadsheet now takes into account [Data Validation](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139705) when submitting forms.** So you can set a rule on your `Age` column to only `allow` `numbers` `greater than` `0`.

When submitting a response which doesnt fit this rule the user is given this message:
[image: Oops...]

**I found out about it after reading [this post.](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/8C-6JMuOGrw/kI0HFmbtjq0J)**

Comment: thanks much. it helped. we also posted a request to improve this feature as it would be much better to limit the inserted value in the field directly ("This field allows only ..."). Current solution is not good for people submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms now include [proper Data Validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

You could put a response validation on the input field that restricts the input to "Numbers," "Between," and then list the limits you mentioned, 1800 and 2012, and then choose your custom error text.